# npm script execution failed (works on CLI command shell)

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I've written an script on `packages.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack"
}
```

As you can see it only runs a `webpack`. 
The problem appears when I'm performing this script (`npm run webpack`):

> 10 verbose lifecycle living-user-platform@0.1.0~webpack: CWD:
>   D:\projects\living\user-platform\project 11 silly lifecycle
>   living-user-platform@0.1.0~webpack: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack' ] 12
>   silly lifecycle living-user-platform@0.1.0~webpack: Returned: code:
>   3221226505  signal: null 13 info lifecycle
>   living-user-platform@0.1.0~webpack: Failed to exec webpack script 14
>   verbose stack Error: living-user-platform@0.1.0 webpack: `webpack` 14
>   verbose stack Exit status 3221226505 14 verbose stack     at
>   EventEmitter. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16) 14
>   verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 14 verbose stack
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7) 14 verbose stack     at
>   ChildProcess. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14) 14 verbose
>   stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 14 verbose stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:885:16) 14 verbose stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)

However, when I perform `webpack` on command shell it works fine.

Which's really the difference between using an `npm script` and using the CLI instead of?

Any ideas?

Comment: The diff between npm script and the cli is that npm script use webpack from your current directory node_modules but webpack cli command uses the global installed webpack. Do they exists in both places? same version?

Comment: Yes. `webpack` is installed on `node_modules` version `"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22"`

Comment: Is it installed globally with the same version?

Comment: Ohh no: `npm list -g --depth=0`
`+-- bower@1.8.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- node-gyp@3.4.0
+-- typings@2.0.0
+-- webpack@1.13.3
+-- webpack-dev-server@1.16.2
-- websocket-driver@0.6.5` How could I revert this?

Comment: Which version do you want to use?

Comment: In my `packages.json` I've set: `"webpack": "2.1.0-beta.22" and `"webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.2"`

Comment: I've already installed `webpack@2.1.0-beta.22` and `webpack-dev-server@2.1.0-beta.2`. However the first problem remains. `webpack` command works fine and `npm run webpack` keeps failing.

Comment: If you run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -v` in your project directory and `webpack -v`. Do you get the same version?